# Check series for convergence or divergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2+(-3)^n}{4^n} $$

I had an idea to decompose this series into the sum of two series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2+(-3)^n}{4^n}  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4^n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-3)^n}{4^n} $$
and already consider the convergence of each of the series.
But as far as I understand, this is not quite true, because we are changing the summation order. And it is not clear what the convergence of an ordinary series and an alternating series will tell us about convergence.

The main problem arises from the fact that

$$ \left | \frac{2+(-3)^n}{4^n} \right | \neq \frac{2+3^n}{4^n} $$
that's why I can't use the Leibniz attribute and work with it any further.
Maybe I don't understand something and then everything is just solved.

Comment: The original series itself is an alternating series. As long as you show the absolute values of the terms converge to zero, you will have convergence.

Comment: Note that $
\left| {\frac{{2 + ( - 3)^n }}{{4^n }}} \right| \le \frac{{2 + 3^n }}{{4^n }} < \frac{{2 \cdot 3^n }}{{4^n }} = 2\left( {\frac{3}{4}} \right)^n 
$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is fine since both series converge indeed

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4^n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-3)^n}{4^n}= 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac 3 4\right)^n$$

which are two geometric series.